# Arduino not driving RGB LED Strip

Tags: arduino, led, power, voltage, amplifier

I'm using Arduino Uno with a [12V RGB Signal Amplifier](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E4JQDKE) and a [12V RGB LED strip](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AQT2G9S). 12VDC is supplied to the amplifier.

However the LED strips does not light up whether the PWN pins are set to either `0` or `255`.

```
   analogWrite(ledPinR, 255);
   analogWrite(ledPinG, 255);
   analogWrite(ledPinB, 255);
```

When set to `255`, the OUTPUT R,G,B pins have a voltage of `6.3 V` to `8.6 V`, while the INPUT R,G,B pins are about `4.7 V`.

The OUTPUT pin voltages does not change whether the INPUT pins are at 0V or 5V.

The RGB strips light up when I connect the `POWER -` terminal to any of the OUTPUT R,G,B terminals.

What can be done to allow the Arduino to light up the LED strips?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens if you disconnect one of the amp inputs from the Arduino and connect it to +5V?

Comment: @JohnHonniball Nothing happens. The LED strip does not light up

Comment: Actually the OUTPUT voltages does not change when the INPUT R,G,B voltages are changed from 0V to 5V.

Comment: Sounds like +5V isn't enough to activate the input. Maybe, as others have said, it's an entirely 12V device. Or there's something else that we haven't spotted yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see this little box is designed to take a 12V low-current signal and amplify it to a 12V high-current signal.

It is not suitable for directly connecting to an Arduino.

You will need three NPN transistors to connect between V+ and each of the R, G and B inputs, and then drive the bases of the transistors through a resistor from the Arduino.

But that's only a wild stab in the dark since there seems to be absolutely no documentation available anywhere.

After much hunting I managed to find this image:

[image]

so it seems it is designed to go midway through a chain of LEDs to power more of them, not be driven by a low voltage device like an Arduino.

Comment: I disconnected Arduino completely from the amplifier, then connected PWER +12V to INPUT V+, and POWER +12V to INPUT R,G,B but the LED strip still does not light up. Does this mean there's also a problem with the amplifier?

Comment: I notice `RGB Controller` in the diagram. That probably outputs 12V signals? Heres another wiring diagram that includes Arduino: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3535/rgb-led-strips-with-arduino

Answer (score 1):

This has been a problem posted on several blogs and forum's - the solve is usualy quite simple. the Amplifier is actualy grounding the negativ R G B points from the LED strip. Thus it does not require 12v as sutch. and the initial sketch of connecting arduino 5v pin to the 12v rail of the amplifier is a sure path to burning your arduino -FAST.

Solve is to remove the 12v from the amplifier. most of them work fine with 5v.

[image: revised proposal to Arduino - Led strip ampifier]

Comment: Do remeber that as you use two Voltages both have to have the GND as common. both minus 12v  and minus 5v hooked to same GND.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This seems plausible, but depends on the device. However, you've now connected 5V to a 12V input on the amplifier device. You also haven't indicated connected the Arduino's power to an appropriate source. Consider using the schematic editor to draw your own diagram.

Comment: Thank you. I ommited to elaborate on the 5v. Thanks for pointing this out. Most of the rgb amplifiers has the 12v bridged. And a diode to limit power to the internal (switching circuit). Check your Amplifier before connecting the 12v. My point was to use one 5v powersource for the amplifier and arduino. And a 12v powersource directly to the LED strip. Both sources with a common minus. I have made several setups like this and never burned arduinos due to 12v  going where you dont want it. See my editing of treadstarters drawing, abow.